# Print out a really small floating-point number

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I have the following code:

```
float test = 1/(10^(15));
std::cout << "test: " << test << std::endl;
```

But I get "test: 0" as the value. I want "test: 0.000000000000001".

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You might want to try double instead of float http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045787/how-many-decimal-places-does-the-primitive-float-and-double-support

Comment: `1/(10^(15))` -- That `^` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie probably because the site suggests "c" as a tag even when you wrote and tagged c++ already

Comment: @SnoozeTime: that's not the issue... keep in mind that the intended exponents are magnitude `15` - well within the -128..127 range supported by `float` - and while the number's not exactly representable, the 23 bits in the `float` will do a fair job.

Comment: @chema989 no, 1e15 is a `double`. There's no [integer literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) format with an `e` in the middle. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, you are right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple problems here.

```
10 ^ 15
```

It looks like you expect "^" to be the exponent operator, that is ten raised to the 15th power.

It is not. In C and C++, "^" is a bitwise exclusive-or operator.

The second problem is that all values in the expression are integer values. This means that `(1/(10^15))` is computed as follows:

1) 10^15=5, remember that `^` is really a bitwise exclusive-or operator.

2) 1/5=0, because these are integer values, this is integer division, which is why you get the value of 0.

The best way to fix this is use scientific notation:

```
float test = 1/(1e15);
std::cout << "test: " << test << std::endl;
```

The scientific notation serves two purposes simultaneously: one, you get the right value, and two, this is automatically a floating point value, so the division is carried out as a floating point division.

Comment: How would I do a non-base of 10? Like with 7^15, 7 as my base and 15 as my exponent?

Comment: Use the [pow() library functions](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/pow.3.html).

Comment: `1e-15` might be nicer than `1/1e15`....

Comment: @daemoner119 why don't read a C++ book first?